# Linux - What causes processes to block aka "disk sleep" on synchronous writes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, process, storage, blocking

...as in, for example using dd to dump an ISO image to a thumb drive, or such. At the end of the transfer, the process doing the (afaik synchronous) write is left in 'disk sleep' status for several seconds before exiting, returning to the prompt or whatever. I think it doesn't even respond to SIGKILL if you try to kill -9 it.

If i remember, this didn't happen in the early days of GNU/Linux, or on other Unix systems. Just curious, what causes it?

Comment: "*At the end of the transfer, the process doing the (afaik synchronous) write ...*" - What are you calling the "*end of the transfer*"? Are you implying there are other "*processes*" involved in this transfer other than the "*process doing the ... write*"? Did you explicitly specify a synchronous transfer (for both data & metadata), or are you just guessing that it's "*synchronous*"? What block size are you using? Something ridiculously large like `bs=1G`?

Comment: "using `dd` … (afaik synchronous)" – What [`conv=` and `oflag=`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508726/108618) did you use?

Comment: @sawdust just dd if=somefile.iso of=/dev/someusbstick with no other options to dd ...when you send it SIGUSR1 during transfer, it outputs info about the progress. When it reaches 100% of number of blocks, it freezes for a good 30 seconds without responding to any signals, then exits and the shell returns to its prompt. AFAIK by default dd would initiate a synchronous transfer with block size of 512 bytes if i remember. If that's the physical block size of the device being written to, there shouldn't be any buffering or delays before physically writing the actual data to it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski None, see my comment above.

Comment: Please [edit] and add information to the question. All relevant information should be in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The wait is most likely for flushing out the memory cache to
the target disk.

This happens when using the option of `conv=fdatasync`
(or `fsync`), telling `dd` to make sure that the data gets
written to the physical device.

Another possibility for a wait is if you enter the
`sync` command immediately after the `dd` command.

Reference : [dd(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html).